# function not producing correct mean output in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I am working on a homework assignment for an r programming course on Coursera. I have a directory with weather data readings for 332 monitors. It is 172,385 observations of 4 variables. The variables or date, sulfate, nitrate, and monitor id. I've written the function below and gotten it to work, but it is not returning the correct values. This is my first real experience with programming and it's a homework assignment so I'm really just looking for hints or advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my function:

```
polutantmean14 <- function(directory, polutant = "nitrate", id = 1:332) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  dat <- data.frame()
  for ( i in 1:332) {
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
  }
  dat_subset <- dat[which(dat[, "ID"] == id), ]
  mean(dat_subset[, polutant], na.rm= TRUE)
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> polutantmean14("specdata", polutant = "sulfate", id = 1:10)
>
> [1] 3.838328
>
> Warning message:
>   In dat[, "ID"] == id :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

The function returns 3.838328 but for the given arguments I am supposed to get 4.064.

Like I mentioned earlier, I am brand new to programming and this is homework so I'm really just looking for advice and guidance on where my error is.

Comment: id is a vector from 1:332... so you can not compare it with ==

Comment: not related to your question but you have `id=1:332` as a default in your function but then in your for loop it is hardcoded as 1:332 instead of using the `id` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: Ok, so I exchanged == for %in% and it worked, giving me all the answers I'm supposed to get. My next question is why? What is the difference between the two and why would %in% work when == didn't?

Comment: `a %in% b` looks for `a` in vector `b` and returns `TRUE` if it's there somewhere.  Be careful though: if `a` is a vector of length >1, then a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s will be returned.  For safety, you could use `if(sum(a %in% b, na.rm = T) != 0)` which would mean that at least one element of `a` matches at least one element of `b`.

Comment: Instead of using sum !=0 you could just use any

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a vector of length 332 with a vector of length 10.

R (unlike MATLAB) will let you compare vectors of different lengths, but will give a warning if the length of the longer one is not a multiple of the length of the shorter one. That is if `mod(length(longerVec),length(shorterVec)) != 0`

Long story short: Rethink and rewrite your code. ;-)